# Kendo UI Grid React Columns

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the grid component of kendo-react-ui and having an issue while scrolling to the last column So I want to add arrow buttons for users to go through all the columns without scrolling. Is there any method for that in kendo-ui?

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked, there isn't you will have to implement your own buttons and on click toggle visibility of the respective end columns. The sizing might be weird too - I'm not sure how well this will be handled but it's straight forward to try.